# How is Facebook Paper's web view so smooth?

Tags: ios, facebook, uiwebview

I'm a little late to the Facebook Paper party. I think the app is really neat, and I've noticed a lot of people here are dying to recreate the slick animations. But I'm really interested in how they got the web view so dang buttery smooth. Every time I've ever encountered a UIWebView, it's sooooo obvious that's what it is, because the performance plummets.

These are my theories:

- Maybe they're removing unnecessary chunks from the HTML here and there (like ads, etc.) before displaying it?
- Maybe they worked with content providers to give them custom, slimmed-down pages?
- Maybe it's not a UIWebView at all, and they're simply parsing the DOM and displaying the content however they want?

Any insights on this?

Comment: I'm going to take a look at this a little later and answer if nobody does by then.

Comment: Just following up, I introspected the app with Spark Inspector and did not find anything too useful or insightful.